# Diagonal factorization of upper triangluar matrix to unit uppper triangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How to compute Diagonal factorization of upper triangluar matrix to unit uppper triangular matrix.
i.e U = D*M where U is upper triangular; D is diagonal; M is unit upper triangular.

Comment: Consider forming a diagonal matrix from the diagonal elements of your upper triangular matrix, and see what happens if you premultiply the inverse of this diagonal matrix to your triangular matrix.

Comment: What does unit upper triangular mean? Does it mean that the matrix is upper triangular and every element on the diagonal is 1?

Answer (score 0):

Hy actually it was trivial, i couldn't think enough.
D will be the diagnoal entries of U;
M will be the unit entries in the diagonal and each entry in the row will be divided by the corresponding diagonal value of D.

Thnaks:)